# UICollectionView - Layout Strategy

Tags: objective-c, ios7, swift, uicollectionview, xcode-storyboard

I am new to the UICollectionView and am doing a very basic sample project in Swift.
So far I was able to successfully generate a listing of 7 items on the screen, and when you tap one, it takes you to the details view for that particular item. There will always be 7 items.

What is a sensible way to go about laying out the items such that:

-The first 4 cells always appear on the first row 
-The remaining 3 cells always appear beneath the first row of 4
-The items are all centered, so in other words the 3 items are centered with repeat to the screen or 4 items above it.

Like this: 
 x x x x 
  x x x

Not like this: 
x x x x 
x x x

If that makes sense?

Is this a good candidate for a custom flow? Or is it likely something I can achieve with some with the default collection view?

Thanks so much for your advice!

Comment: Why use a collection view at all if you only have 7 items that are always on screen? I think it will be easier to accomplish this with 7 UIViews spaced appropriately with layout constraints.

Comment: Think so? Ok perfect thanks for your advice, I was thinking about that as well. Should I make my own nib or something (sorry i'm new to this / trying to read up as much as possible) or should I just create 7 views with 7 labels on them?

Comment: It depends on your needs. If you're only displaying text, you should only need the 7 labels, no need to enclose them in views. You can make them in a xib or storyboard, it doesn't matter.